# Unable to use exposed bean which uses RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, annotations

I am creating a war which is going to use a class from a jar file. 
Now this jar file has a exposed a bean in its `associationApplicationContext.xml` which uses the [@Required](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) annotation on some of its properties for initialization.

**associationApplicationContext.xml**

e.g.

```
<!-- processes @Required annotations-->
  <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
  <!-- The client bean to access the association rest web service -->
  <bean id="associationClient" class="com.springtest.client.AssociationClientImpl">
      <property name="associationRestClient" ref="associationServiceRestClient" />
  </bean>
```

So inside the `AssociationClient` the property `associationRestClient` has `@Required` tag over its setter method.

```
@Required
public void setAssociationRestClient(final AssociationRestClient associationRestClient) {
        this.associationRestClient= associationRestClient;
 }
```

Now, as when I try to use this bean in my war file -

I have already put the jar dependency in pom.xml of war file
Already put the `contextConfigLocation` in `web.xml` as

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
    classpath:/associationApplicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Using the bean from inside the war file in another `applicationcontext.xml` file as

```
 <import resource="classpath:/associationApplicationContext.xml"/>
    <bean id="requestHandlerV1"
            class="com.springtest.application.RequestHandlerV1">
            <property name="associationClient" ref="associationClient"></property>      
    </bean>
```

Here the property `associationClient` is not getting initialized because it is not able to find the reference to bean `associationRestClient` which is `associationServiceRestClient`

I am getting

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'associationServiceRestClient' is defined

How can I get the object of `associationClient` initialized here ?

PS : I cannot change the implementation which uses [@Required](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Required.html) annotation

Comment: In import resource, isn't classpath:/associationApplicationContext.xml.xml (.xml.xml) a typo?

Comment: Corrcted it. But it is an example only. I cant put the original file.

Comment: Can you post the snippet from web.xml where applicationcontext.xml is being set as config param for a servlet?

Comment: <servlet>
    <servlet-name>JerseySpringWebApplication</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
      <param-value>classpath:/applicationcontext.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  
  <!--URl for web service -->
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JerseySpringWebApplication</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

Comment: Here. I posted it. Sorry for the (non) formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following:
In web.xml:

```
    <!-root application context-->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:associationApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>     
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>JerseySpringWebApplication</servlet-name> 
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class> 
        <init-param> 
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name> 
            <param-value>classpath*:applicationcontext.xml</param-value> 
        </init-param> 
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup> 
    </servlet> 
    <!--URl for web service --> 
    <servlet-mapping> 
        <servlet-name>JerseySpringWebApplication</servlet-name> 
        <url-pattern>/service/*</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
```

You don't have to import the associationApplicationContext.xml in applicationcontext.xml as now the root application beans will be visible in applicationcontext.xml. So application Context.xml will be like:

```
    <mvc:annotation-config/>
    <bean id="requestHandlerV1" class="com.springtest.application.RequestHandlerV1">
        <property name="associationClient" ref="associationClient"></property>      
    </bean>
```

*Assuming you are invoking the controller through rest call.
If you still see issue with this, post your log.

Comment: I got this issue resolved. 
Actually I needed to import the associationApplicationContext.xml into the contextConfigLocation of servlet instead of root. 
That was it was able to recognize and load the beans which are having properties marked as @Required 

Thanks for help anyways. :)